# How can I place a link at the bottom of the viewport on first page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to achieve an effect similar to the one seen [here](https://www.dropbox.com) on Dropbox's landing page. Notice that there's a link at the bottom of your browser viewport ('learn more'). This is always at the bottom of the page on first load. However, it's not fixed to the bottom of the window as you can scroll past it.

Any idea how to achieve this? A CSS or jquery solution is fine.

Comment: Try using Dev Tools or Firebug and just look at what they did to achieve that effect? Looks like simple absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

It's a link within a `div` which has the following CSS (the `div`'s):

```css
position: absolute;
bottom: 50px;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
cursor: pointer;
```

The important parts there are `position:absolute` and `bottom:50px`

Comment: It's probably equally important that all of it's parent containers have been set to `height: 100%` including the `body` and `html` elements.

Comment: Whilst this does position a link at the bottom of the page, it will always be fixed to the bottom. You can't scroll past it to content further down the page as seen on the Dropbox example.